# Flutter app crashes after requesting for permission for Geo locator package

Tags: android, flutter, geolocation, flutter-dependencies, geolocator

I'm using Telephone and Geolocator package to get location and send that location as a SMS when I press the Send button.
But my app crashes after I accept the permission for requesting location, but it only **Happens on first try of debugging. When I re run the app the second time it works just fine**

Here is my main dart code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:telephony/telephony.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';



void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              await sendSMS();
            },
            child: Text("Send SMS"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future <void> sendSMS() async {
    final Telephony telephony = Telephony.instance;
    bool? permissionsGranted = await telephony.requestPhoneAndSmsPermissions;
    print(permissionsGranted);

    Position currentPosition = await _getCurrentLocation();
    print("Get location function was a success");
    String message = "My current location is: LAT ${currentPosition.latitude}, LNG ${currentPosition.longitude}";
    await telephony.sendSms(to: "03215272603", message: message);
    print("SMS Sent");
  }

  Future <Position> _getCurrentLocation() async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;

    // Test if location services are enabled.
    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {

      // Location services are not enabled don't continue
      // accessing the position and request users of the
      // App to enable the location services.
      return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
    }
    print("This is service enabled");
    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();

    }

    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      // Permissions are denied forever, handle appropriately.
      return Future.error(
          'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
    }

    print("we have reached here");
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    print("We get the live location");
    return position;
  }
}
```

Here is my permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Here is when the app crashes:

```
  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.example.sms, PID: 14173
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=109, result=-1, data=Intent { a
ct=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.sms/com.example.sms.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply
 already submitted
         at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5042)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5086)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(Unknown Source:0)
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2071)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7555)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:469)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:963)
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
         at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply(DartMessenger.java:430)
         at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler$1.error(MethodChannel.java:272)
         at com.shounakmulay.telephony.sms.SmsMethodCallHandler.execute(SmsMethodCallHandler.kt:169)
         at com.shounakmulay.telephony.sms.SmsMethodCallHandler.onRequestPermissionsResult(SmsMethodCallHandler.kt:374)
         at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry$FlutterEngineActivityPluginBinding.onRequestPermissionsResult(Flutte
rEngineConnectionRegistry.java:777)
         at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterEngineConnectionRegistry.java:409)
         at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.ja
va:757)
         at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(FlutterActivity.java:748)
         at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:7786)
         at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7637)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5038)
         ... 9 more
```